# adding manul data to form requests in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this fuction which is getting data from my form add create row in database

```
$project = Project::create($request->only(['title', 'report_type', 'user_id', 'body', 'attachment', 'projectclass', 'budget', 'deadline']));
```

now I want add another data into it but that data not coming from form it generates in controller,

```
'pnum' => mt_rand(1000, 9223372036854775807)
```

How can I add my `pnum` data to the function above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take request data into variable which will be of type array and add there your new element

```
$insertData = $request->only(['title', 'report_type', 'user_id', 'body', 'attachment', 'projectclass', 'budget', 'deadline']);

$insertData['pnum'] = mt_rand(1000, 9223372036854775807);
```

Now you can pass this variable to create method

```
$project = Project::create($insertData);
```

Answer (score 0):

first keep all the the data of your request to the variable eg: $data
and then follow the following

```
$data= $request->all();
$data['pnum'] = mt_rand(1000, 9223372036854775807);
$project = Project::create($data);
```